# There is no set to which every set belongs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Elements of Set Theory by Enderton H.B.

This is probably a simple misunderstanding, but I have become confused by the proof of the first theorem in the book.

The theorem is as follows: "There is no set to which every set belongs"

The proof starts by saying:

"Let A be a set; we will construct a set not belonging to A". Let
$$
B=\{x\in A:x\notin x\}
$$

This goes on to show that $B\notin A$.

I understand the rest of the proof, but feel that this initial construction is not well founded.

Is the initial set A that was chosen the set to which every set belongs? If not, how can we say $x\in A$. And if this is the case then it seems to make more sense to me, but nowhere has that been specified.

Comment: You are confused about the basic [set-builder notation](http://www.mathwords.com/s/set_builder_notation.htm). Given the set $A$, the set $B$ is defined as the subset of $A$ consisting of those elements of $A$ that do not belong to themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why should $B$ not be well founded (or rather: properly defined)? The *comprehension* used to define $B$, i.e. to select elements from a given set by a specific property, is the main method to describe a set. Here, $B$ is the subset of $A$ that consists of precisely those elements o$x$ of $A$ for which the deus-ex-machina property $x\notin x$ holds. (Btw. "(well) founded" has a very specific meaning in set thoery that is not the same as "defined")

The initial set $A$ was not the set to which every set belongs - because there is no such set (as theproof is about to show). The proof starts "Let $A$ be a set." Hence $A$ is just any set. If there *were* a universal set, then you *might* pick $A$ to be the universal set. However, the proof does not assume so. Instead it exhibits a specific set $B$ that is not element of $A$ and hence shows that the *arbitrary* set $A$ is not universal. In other words: There is no universal set.

You could rewrite the proof such that $A$ is universal, i.e do a proof by contradiction: "Assume otherwise and let $A$ be a set such that every set is an element of $A$. ... yada yada ... Hence $B\notin A$, contradicting the assumption that $A$ is universal. We conclude that the assumption was false.  In other words: There is no universal set."
A more direct proof, such as in the text, is often more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful answer. I guess what I am confused about is "Construct a set not belonging to A" is the same as "$x \in A$ such that $x\notin x$". How can we say the initial $x\in A$?

Comment: @Dansmith Nobody said that $A$ may not contain any element $x$ (and even if so ...), and also $B$ as constructed is not the $x$. Instead $B$ is a set that contains certain of these $x$ (namely those for which $x\notin x$). Formally, the set $B$ described by the notation $B=\{\,x\in A : \Phi(x)\,\}$ is the unique set with the property $$\forall x\colon\ \bigl(x\in B\iff (x\in A\land \Phi(x))\bigr) $$ The existance of such a set for any given set $A$ and property $\Phi$ is of course one of the *axioms* of set theory (and perhaps the one that's most chracteristic of what we want sets to be).

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now, thanks.